# Are there domains available to security companies for testing spam?

Tags: email, spam

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm not very experienced in this particular area.

I work for a large corporation who has, in my mind, a rather paranoid view of security (developers had command prompt access removed for a few days because it was a "security risk", until enough people shouted that a) it was stopping devs actually doing any work, and b) powershell was still available). Over the past few days, following an email about remaining vigilant for malicious emails, we've started to receive some malicious emails.

For each email, I've checked the mail header out of curiosity, and they've all had the sender IP as an IP address registered to the company, but sent from different domains registered to a third parties, the latest to one in Switzerland.

What are the chances that these are genuine malicious emails sent using the company's mail server, or are there domains that a company's internal IT security department can utilize to send out "test spam" emails to employees?

EDIT: as requested, header is below

```
Received: from AM4PR44MB1666.eurprd69.prod.outlook.com (12.104.79.15) by
 VI1PR04MB1679.eurprd69.prod.outlook.com (12.104.85.17) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id
 15.1.1198.14 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 26 Jun 2017 16:24:44 +0000
Received: from DB5PR64CA0024.eurprd69.prod.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:e400:598c::34) by AM4PR44MB1666.eurprd69.prod.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:e400:59e6::16) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id 15.1.1198.14; Mon, 26
 Jun 2017 16:24:43 +0000
Received: from AM5ETR02FT524.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e1e::209) by DB5PR64CA0024.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:598c::34) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id 15.1.1198.14 via
 Frontend Transport; Mon, 26 Jun 2017 16:24:43 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=fail (sender IP is xx.xx.xx.xx)
 smtp.mailfrom=salary-standard.com; tomatoes.microsoftemail.com; dkim=none
 (message not signed) header.d=none;tomatoes.microsoftemail.com; dmarc=none
 action=none header.from=salary-standard.com;
Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of salary-standard.com does
 not designate xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;
 helo=reply.example.com;
Received: from reply.example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) by
 AM5ETR02FT524.mail.protection.outlook.com (12.102.8.124) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_1, cipher=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) id 15.1.1199.9
 via Frontend Transport; Mon, 26 Jun 2017 16:24:43 +0000
Subject: [Potentially Suspicious] Salaries 2016 - The Financial Services & Insurance
 Benchmark Study
Authentication-Results-Original: tompuss.example.com; spf=None
 smtp.pra=financial.services-benchmark@salary-standard.com; spf=PermError
 smtp.mailfrom=Rupert@salary-standard.com; spf=None
 smtp.helo=postmaster@mail08.salary-standard.com
X-SBRS: -2.9
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="===============1289836573990547394=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Rupert de Mol, CEO " <financial.services-benchmark@salary-standard.com>
To: Someone Smart <someone.smart@example.com>
Message-ID: <20170626162429.30246.40872@example-email>
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 16:24:31 +0000
Return-Path: Rupert@salary-standard.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: c9cac624-ffa6-4fda-be71-08d4bcafda62
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 396b38cc-aa65-492b-bb4e-3d94ed25a97b:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-HT: Tenant
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:xx.xx.xx.xx;IPV:CAL;SCL:-1;CTRY:FR;EFV:NLI;SFV:SKN;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:-1;SRVR:AM4PR44MB1666;H:reply.example.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: =?us-ascii?Q?1;AM5ETR02FT524;1:VM/7nqVXvbNr+JLLHHlYkNqSXt1gP6a1cdEQA7YHh4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?mA0NFHpMF1o4WPcOe8m2qck9OJL5mAj+G8Tne+TED7LDmZB2RfhJzfjOweNP?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?J9TNkBYYheIXZS5X2Sh9RZJZjY9Co+WdPc184L4RO9I+Ivip3PahsGJioO+2?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?TMNj3LOjuiyPFs7qPvwpzZQJJ41JFvinUdMFiK4WUjX/b04vAJRCtoBT7pji?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?E0CvRItH0+6cMNM2LwgyBD+bElCXA0A+1PMehy2sghIRwDQueTC7Dp7Vt5Dv?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?OYZ+YtG0jol93DCCb2AfbTn7H7aU9cfiakxyU6EyRraJ4aQOUMlq7gRc3YF+?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?7U0T7ugbDVLJPQIPdNxx+ao2ROPck1rBCqKeiuIA40AgrLyh1XzqBJN6c+N2?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?iio+fnpMnOvi9k7vf2ZhNVoac9ElSQbc82F1NcxIvr3V86SA1sM2uOC6K02o?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?NtE6NFLkiuAUk9r5KBwmPTt6GQQA6jBqW5ckc7CeFpHHJplLsH1Y5UTx5Xxw?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?dGs9J/5o/KsesTdfvPo3wN0Pix50MNuM29gSgnR6a4C18gaXFgTft9UO8vET?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DQTHBtshItcDaWnFtu9h+ELGiI/IlEfLJmMuf8sAplmIOaSgGielDnSdnV/Y?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?a5z4lm/8r4IXQbD61DV3D+Zx5AM6sshfMoDm229sPeR6loHcgFcZrcwOGsYP?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?sGxli75jucalh/cgSdnMI8bNbDurivHDT6uOr6ng5DY4sqvzenrmtoP3jY4d?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?1GKnCxP65jxyOPrO8niXQhmlS5cH+ssKT708wjKsDL4CqflvHk60sPGYnx40?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?c5aZoV80WrRnEfZDv1Pkp0giP/DLTtxXDilVG6Xa48otmY7I8WJXtB8OypN2?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?YmNQqXOIOxmEnLh9OwJHADjzrmG4rPSQqtDxr89xD8zmtgxCZM4svn+H+vlC?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?P4fjjjRN2g5JSuSsqUOkKnGV8HVcFTeDXnbkYU6MigVZzVE29U/6McamU2o2?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?U2ZH/nTzzNaQrlrByP+nOawLy+AIfEW84DKYxJcYpjtiKuqF8rLmGFTMf0oz?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?nq6XmdYWYrBAQeQLU9Y0QOYzcdnsyQh76JAPlOJ4BtcHV/JQ=3D=3D?=
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: c9cac624-ffa6-4fda-be71-08d4bcafda62
X-Microsoft-Antispam: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(300000500095)(300135000095)(300000501095)(300135300095)(22001)(300000502095)(300135100095)(23075)(300000503095)(300135400095)(49563074)(71702078)(300000504095)(300135200095)(300000505095)(300135600095);SRVR:AM4PR44MB1666;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;3: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
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: AM4PR44MB1666:
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: =?us-ascii?Q?1;AM4PR44MB1666;25:lmziY2+IVvCJxoZmr1WX7EvfdsR3msjBagaSiJLHH?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?FScHNVN8/09nw2A5fy3vFyWH2whHVLr5NvCHoYRayCz43+TFhSSU3emN5bg5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?eokewhZd6DGX+QmUJ5S/ozOslW9Yx44XDneEsq3i5B89Cyi5VgK8KE0znnwD?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?nOysiAsAPb5UPqLbt51ReOwGeYLRopHhc8SrmtbFoeZ0wsLpe/BuIafrnSzs?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?fFhc7rVnWn4CMleNcXYqHgDPQEntV0D+pE5aH62KfhlqHdSCbzgnbryEG/eW?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?dVa6piks/uRclgegzKWwJ0BdbnlH2GgihfeyBLDSP8xIUaAUBlwE7UCoYmrb?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?TIYXt9djCPUGwHckvBkVg3CI4yhFz57LvCsWsuagDtfqMmpSHpeheflS6Bk7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?d5HrGqFW14XNeQFLHvsWY9xRKRSxqOtuRG345ghkHGA4/zmDyY5ZXm/ylvD4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?B928Zm3g13J2RTzk1/uNqsMhpoxK3YJxoo8gF2/epzBGC9gK7PdTOX7kRDpF?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?iIoB+NyIzJJipQAwKiKmXraD2bFb4i/fF/AQ0TM1GrgKwyGErQiLlXAfCBxa?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?BtOQIr1N7vO46TJkSBPwbahW8lWqPIsC/mqmYgyeqNaTd1a6BR3l75Kd/vZE?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ZV5kSB60VyGm3NIibbpqBx7gHIA5vT+DuPmyaaFKD81B6XAQ5JX8wuSMZrdg?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?8HHS9CAA8lfafPXUo91KERu0uoCwFVXZVZiD7Pmbo5iPHPQxsGyw26ORAVeE?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?izXBVTblDVRuOOdZ+QDN/uL6m6Y5KPSZ26e3gUkZ2EWN65YZZa474bWYNOFK?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?XPE2p7poTMwcni+ukH6Q82rq86RJTPoFF+HCHLpanHDrQ+kxBeST32R/rDqe?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?wkqEz+SaVGIByIexMwdQ9nn88Iy4iU38XyqdYD1BtjI6B0rt2EWzx64syYsd?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?bfuDXB3oAcwlHKTPw2B9N4SKwM1msgGFa+ef+GS+A=3D=3D?=
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;31: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
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;20: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
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101)(100105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(102415395)(41303006);SRVR:AM4PR44MB1666;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000800101)(100110000095)(100000801101)(100110300095)(100000802101)(100110100095)(100000803101)(100110400095)(100000804101)(100110200095)(100000805101)(100110500095);SRVR:AM4PR44MB1666;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;4:WIkIgZ0WNrGX+6pN7RMq+B6LvvDRv3FNVBnNdAZbZ2uxsp6WYe/otLsilxmBUpXQ/q9jXB6eb3cWLNy0v1+QzQGskMD0noTJmKhM5Ln+AjNTTBIwV8kiUskPDeGDBoviJ+VgU6F/t8YCp7rfp9qZb5off7Ps5FyM239fFdux960rTyvccJ1m4e+9CfyHDuBuPxcQIAmvyCnlZCQfq1FArR7abBtP0qQUq04kYJd3jd0xQ4QD2Ij2AE5tuvgmuXLxsw9/rbIyDj/IHfasB9kxsn8FIN8rKFBRFyKkj7sGBShTL9DYHdwAZrkSI30wy9zee6ukeGcqkXBBTtjrd5kqTrYFPxK6QPNY2tja2UdojmOwd7daik0Wwy8GItLj0z2BFy8an7PvUnkBrD7F5WvFbuqFiEmdyX6hsPNj01X+x4ekUI+fbfZSgdYepd+4aDywVQldqeR6wl8cdKdhNsrL2fSmOZn0nTMZcNWIolCzO5M=;23:Ds4ZNwuriSzh9zfS1SSRYMiB91yX7uJv5X0amScPSlCaKfnsVc6ew1OLh0Z6moePNQrt3yDDloXGHFN9c7sxxr+suoezp5JhXxn6gfumuJ+BQ/Q84z5xOIkUR8SoJBtVy5NwQ2NM368sCha1byirKvRTRJDAxv34IeUOsla9yq+knmI1prbj5OsK/apbkdD2
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;6: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
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;5: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;24:WHkk01I0gnvGSGbsvCqNzNseb68HokWoJUuSswC8fga7MwN7FJSET7tiOKf4r29aVngPm38PS/zMOuvELv5NUWdkpiBnXhClqYaMaVDihKQ=
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: SKN
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;7: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
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;AM4PR44MB1666;20:zXO8lpFJKYvLYPUtTn5OKKV6HtayCLtKzT2Uq386Ad9i15pFJ2Wg2BxGkSbWU9cXyjbGZ3cUZW7ZGMRuCP0McQY1kzMQkODRcA6jO4hQ8hN/ycnxMml4pJf6ULXWcrNc86Q7p457upNKOua6cSMW0Rp2U5cYV40CesSSDv1uOTFa/6MoIudBapAp7mDFWPxQkBzWgLN6besgGraPEF/OXe+8A+krdLgX7cyRA9OUzjPIgq5a/XPRZHWg97ndofS+
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 26 Jun 2017 16:24:43.1223
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 396b38cc-aa65-492b-bb0e-3d94ed25a97b
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: AM4PR44MB1666
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: AM5ETR02FT524.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.4335628
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(520000050)(520011016)(750028)(400001001223)(400125100095)(61617095)(400001002128)(400125200095);
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;VI1PR04MB1679;9:nAE543Rl+wZ9GK3tKSq6QDf+ODRG3DxA8Xqq4cW5BPQOXu8hihJiksBGWwSHVBnWHUUWLhVTKsCRCuHCENgKQK4B5GA1snQEeHJz/Pdj6tMOgrXs1SzG1WS8gq15LrN657EYup2n+Aawcx0l9wDIbRZPQJc/t8l5Zh5/2sHykVeHmxyvee69at0/RS6pMhlsgPuKX5Z7jAgRPqcwh/nTBLo3aBYdSI8VANjJGECYck4oODSVStF3hHCw2CNv8XmnVYXbucAdNeJ6CA5HHseKnUYDTnTjCx9smFA13dkDJ9vzBV8DR/vGonI1MojQSFE8eXzhLjGBXX9BHyW5CCuYsgEL8DIIzHawgHyN4zccVuNytqHUjTAI52rnvDzP4rgtqli3o8uWikUKwQ/wnaKmQwaHnl9ZXZ1prb7Prz83HKLLM4sdNfLKGXbOXrNg2mry0qzC7y8Pkt7Dtdzb1I4mRSBq6FblNERsOxm7Eb6vmOGq9RgepkEgXSW6VUNVkiS8UnJCqMaky01rEw4/3jsTZO1Nm2PbSb76tp1TJyxHFSTzcVMfcXFm30VVeGObcBQC/AOZq2uf7ZAo71J8jVmcML0CC12GHOa+b45zUshx5MNUR0JU0wLeoFCwN6dkf9uZ41FdxHfRg5yvazXPzvVOhHqtYQ2P9j5SlG4Dd+f06W5nmdTFuGxJSvEuEf9VNAAEpmhrC7dUgZRappXOe+Ji1CTTFo3kXe0PrtYAubtGVuQAxiMyg84uLvgBICtYt5nRxztlhmp628IAbaZ2exyTOj4Yj8hpNrLn8UUL8bd3wcER78fBBKaFXq3tnf2Mwg/I
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;VI1PR04MB1679;27:spq9x+j0o08PPPi1Lhd0OTBgYAAJL2KEc6hkT7MxJL3A5fFDSdNqcI06s+94PfUoYCR0bCE1qIQktUbQMf/h7siX2v8nG1fIwsRHwHP/DAbqDIaZQoyBE9/aI/52iIGS3rlE7FBKERu1A4isCEBf+A==
```

Comment: Lots of information in the header can be faked. With only relying on the few information you provide it is impossible to make a reliable statement. More might be said if one could have a closer look at the source code (including full header) of several of these mails and probably about the amount of such spam/phishing mails you usually get too. But of course, mails can be send from lots of different IP addresses and one does not need special domains for this.

Comment: Mail headers can have wide variations - so perhaps you could post some of it - **after suitably obfuscating specific IP addresses / domain names / email addresses.**
If not, we could still speculate (spam isn't all that rare, and there aren't too many new techniques out there), but it would still be a guessing game without specific headers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich fair enough, I've included the header in the question if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: @Sas3 I've included the header in the question after hopefully obfuscating enough details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the analysis of the mail header shown and the provided information:

- The initial Received header (at the bottom) shows from which IP address this mail was sent in the first place. According to your mail the IP address in the header (obfuscated) is owned by your company. While the header could be faked I doubt this because all of the Received headers are typical for outlook.com.
- The SPF results show a Fail, i.e. it was not expected that anybody in the acclaimed sender domain sends mail from this IP address. This makes it very likely that the sender is spoofed.

This together means that very likely mails with a spoofed sender where sent from IP addresses owned by your company. This might be either be done intentionally as a security check by your company as you assume. If not then it might be caused by an infected system inside your company (i.e. part of spamming botnet) which is probably worse.

Comment: Great, thank you. Given the rather coincidental timing of these emails, a few other recent changes, and the lack of any such emails beforehand, I think there's a fair chance they're part of a security check.